# History.pushState and page refresh

Tags: javascript

I started looking at HTML5 new history API

However, I have one question. How can one handles the page refresh?

For example a user clicks a link, which is handled by a js function, which

asynchronously loads the content of the page

changes the URL with history.pushState()

The the user refreshes the page, but the URL of course does not exist on the server

How do you handle situations like this? With the hash solution there was no issue there

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform server side redirection for copy and pasted fake URLs
It all depends on what server side technology you're using. There is no JavaScript way but writing a crazy function in your 404 page that redirect user based on incoming URL that is not a good solution.

Comment: So you need the server side to handle requests based on whether they are ajax or a full page. If they are ajax return just a portion of the page, otherwise return the whole document. Correct?

Comment: Yes, seems to be a good scenario. Most people use blah.com/dir/page/ajax/condition/condition... so you can redirect to the "page" or even further and call your ajax or even apply conditions to your ajax. It all depends on your web app

Answer (score 6):

This does require the server-side support. The ideal use of `.pushState` is to allow URLs from JavaScript applications to be handled intelligently by the server.

This could be either by re-serving the same JavaScript application, and letting it inspect `window.location`, or by rendering the content at that URL on the server as you would for a normal web application. The specifics obviously vary depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

> The the user refreshes the page, but the URL of course does not exist
>   on the server

What do you mean by this? I have a feeling your assumption is wrong. 
Actually yes, the point is it is the developer who should provide (serverside or clientside) implementation of url-to-pagestate correspondence.

If, once again, I've get the question right.

Comment: Hi. I mean how would you handle the page refresh since the URL does not exist. You need to handle this server side, right? But I find this to be a bit of counter productive. If of course I am not missing something

Comment: @Thomas, OK, let me try again to understand you. Say, you have a page with div, you're clicking that div and it's height changes. We want to reflect this event in the URL. First of all, there are two options here: we can change height, and then, change somehow (hash, pushState) URL. OR we can change url, somehow track that url has been changed and hence change div's height. About which approach exactly we are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC on your server, you can add the following to your RegisterRoutes function:

```
       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
       );
```

This will send all requests to Index action of your HomeController and your UI will handle the actual route.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for a JS-only solution, use the `popstate` event on `window`. Please see [MDN - popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) for full details, but essentially this event is passed the state object you gave to `pushState` or `replaceState`. You can access this object like `event.state` and use it's data to determine what to do, ie show an AJAX portion of a page.

I'm not sure if this was unavailable in 2011 but this is available in all modern browsers (IE10+), now.