# How to replace content of div tag using JavaScript on back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets, history.js

My question is almost similar to question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067419/history-pushstate-and-page-refresh) here.

I am have a standard sidebar homepage, which executes ajax to replace text inside a div tag and show context. All works fine except the back button. The back button redirects to login page.

These are the things I tried : (I am using servlets)
Without any javascript, user is sent to login.jsp on back button, (session is not invalidated).
I have written code in login.jsp to redirect to homepage when user is already logged in.

```
access = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("access").toString());
if (access == 1) {
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("ajaxContent?url=homepage");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    //ajaxContent is the servlet loads the sidebar. With the content of homepage in div tag.
}
```

But back button just displays the previous page, so the java code to check session is never executed.

I tried to add a onbeforeunload function to alert the user on back button.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "Your work will be lost.";
    };
```

But it also displays the alert when saving forms saying "Your data will not be saved", well, that's not a very good way to accept forms, right?

Lastly I tried history.pushState function to replace the history when ever the ajax function is called.

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'Previous','www.example.com/ajaxContent?url=homepage');
```

But that just replaces the url in the browser but doesn't load the page. On multiple clicks, it displays login.jsp again. (obviously)

I also found this page which has source code to disable the [back button entirely](https://www.viralpatel.net/demo/javascript-disable-browser-back-button/), but I would prefer to make the back button the replace the div tag with the previous content that was in there.

Comment: pushstate just changes the history list and url it doesnt affect page contents you have to manually do that, eg through the popstate event

Comment: so what is your question? please ask exactly **one** question.

Comment: reply your title: because pushstate doesn't designed to do it. (you use the wrong function)